# Correct was to pass array from Metal Kernel function to local function

Tags: metal

I am working on converting a computational model from Cuda to Metal.

I have some global arrays of structs that I am trying to pass to a function from a kernel function.

I'm getting the following error:

> 1. Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'float3 device[32]' to 'float3 *' (aka 'vector_float3 *') for 2nd argument

For the testFunction.

Here is the sample code:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

struct DOBJ
{
    int      num_vertex;        /* Number of vertcies */
    float3   vert       [32];  /* Rotated on CPU */    
};

bool testFunction(
                          uint num_vertex_B,
                          float3 Vertex_B[32])
{
}

kernel void TestKernel( device DOBJ *VolumeObject )
{

    int d_index = 5;

    bool SP_Check = testFunction(
                                    VolumeObject[d_index].num_vertex,
                                    VolumeObject[d_index].vert );
}
```

The original formation of the CUDA testFunction had the following format:

```
__device__ bool testFunction(
                          uint num_vertex_B,
                          float3 *Vertex_B)
{
}
```

I have a ton of code that follows this structure in the program. How do I properly format the testFunction to accept Vertex_B?

Some more test code following the comment from warrenm

1. This compiles but I've not tried any run tests yet.
2. You can have two "testFunction"(s) only differing by the memory location of the vector but the exact same code.
3. float3 Vertex_B[5] compiles for the thread memory but not the device memory.

   ```
   #include <metal_stdlib>
   using namespace metal;

   struct DOBJ
   {
       int      num_vertex;        /* Number of vertcies */
       float3   vert       [32];  /* Rotated on CPU */ 
   };

   bool testFunction(uint num_vertex_B, device float3 *Vertex_B) { return false; }

   bool testFunction(uint num_vertex_B, thread float3 *Vertex_B) { return false; }

   bool testFunction2( uint num_vertex_B, float3 Vertex_B[5]) { return false; }

   kernel void VolumeObject_InteractionPolyhedra( device DOBJ *VolumeObject )
   {

       int d_index = 5;

       bool SP_Check = testFunction( VolumeObject[d_index].num_vertex, VolumeObject[d_index].vert);

       // Compiler error: 1. Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'float3 device[32]' to 'float3 *' (aka 'vector_float3 *') for 2nd argument
       // bool SP_Check2 = testFunction2( VolumeObject[d_index].num_vertex, VolumeObject[d_index].vert);

       thread float3 *vertList;
       bool SP_Check3 = testFunction( 5, vertList);

       bool SP_Check4 = testFunction2( 5, vertList);
   }
   ```

Comment: Pointers in different address spaces are different types, so naturally you can have different functions with the same name that differ by signature. That's just ordinary C++ function overloading.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to pass an array by value in C or C++ (of which Metal Shading Language is a dialect). However, your function can take a pointer parameter that refers to the array, as long as the pointer is in the same address space as the original buffer:

```
bool testFunction(uint num_vertex_B, device float3 *Vertex_B)
{
}
```